# Specifying NuGet Metadata using ASP.NET 5 Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The output of an ASP.NET 5 Class Library Project is a Nuget Package (.nupkg). My project.json file is shown below:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Provides boilerplate framework code for an ASP.NET MVC project. ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate is a professional template for building secure, fast, robust and adaptable web applications or sites. It provides the minimum amount of code required on top of the default MVC template provided by Microsoft. You can download the ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate project template on the Visual Studio Gallery or download the code on GitHub.",
  "authors": [ "Muhammad Rehan Saeed" ],
  "tags": [ "ASP.NET MVC MVC6 Boilerplate Muhammad Rehan Saeed Framework" ],
  "projectUrl": "https://github.com/RehanSaeed/ASP.NET-MVC-Boilerplate",
  "licenseUrl": "https://github.com/RehanSaeed/ASP.NET-MVC-Boilerplate/blob/master/LICENSE"
  ...omitted
}
```

There does not seem to be properties for the Title, Icon URL, Summary or Release Notes, Copyright or Language. How can these be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be set just like any other property. Here's what's supported: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime/Project.cs#L223-L238

For your particular case:

```
Title -> "title"
IconURL -> "iconUrl"
Summary -> "summary"
Release Notes -> "releaseNotes"
Copyright -> "copyright"
Language -> "language"
```

Comment: It seems the schema file for the project.json file has not been updated yet with the above changes. The RTM version of Visual Studio should have this.